# A* path finding algorithm. Movement Cost and Heuristic is Inaccurate

Tags: java, algorithm, a-star

My problem is that the movement cost(G cost) of my node and heuristic is inaccurate it does not match with the picture.

Here is the image of what I'm following.There are three labels here and the movement cost is labelled at the bottom left and the heuristic is at bottom right. Label at top-left is the `F = H + G`
[image]

Here is my output. As you can see the movement cost is not the same as the desired output. The red circle is the goal node.

[image]

Also the same with my Heuristic cost.

[image]

```
public class AStarPathFinder implements PathFinder {

private List<Node> open = new ArrayList<Node>();
private List<Node> close = new ArrayList<Node>();
private Node[][] nodes;

private TileMap map;
private Heuristic heuristic;

public AStarPathFinder(TiledMapStage mapStage, Heuristic heuristic) {
    this.heuristic = heuristic;
    nodes = mapStage.getNodes();
    map = mapStage.getMap();
}

@Override
public Path findPath(int startX, int startY, int goalX, int goalY) {
    clearNodes();

    Node goal = nodes[goalX][goalY];
    Node current = nodes[startX][startY];

    open.add(current);
    while (!open.isEmpty()) {

        current = getLowestFcost(open);
        open.remove(current);
        close.add(current);

        if (current == goal) {
            Path path = new Path();
            while (current != null) {
                path.add(current);
                current = current.parent;
            }
            return path;
        }
        // neighbors of current
        for (int x = -1; x < 2; x++) {
            for (int y = -1; y < 2; y++) {
                int dx = current.x + x;
                int dy = current.y + y;

                if (map.isValidLocation(dx, dy)) {
                    if (!map.isWalkable(nodes[dx][dy], x, y) || close.contains(nodes[dx][dy]))
                        continue;

                    float newScore = movementCost(current.g, isDiagonal(x, y));
                    if (!open.contains(nodes[dx][dy])) {
                        open.add(nodes[dx][dy]);
                    } else if (newScore >= nodes[dx][dy].g) continue;

                    nodes[dx][dy].g = newScore;
                    nodes[dx][dy].h = heuristic.estimate(nodes[dx][dy], goal);
                    nodes[dx][dy].f = nodes[dx][dy].g + nodes[dx][dy].h;
                    nodes[dx][dy].parent = current;
                    nodes[dx][dy].label.setText((int) nodes[dx][dy].g + "");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private Node getLowestFcost(List<Node> open) {
    Node lowestNode = open.get(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < open.size(); i++) {
        if (open.get(i).f <= lowestNode.f && open.get(i).h < lowestNode.h) {
            lowestNode = open.get(i);
        }
    }
    return lowestNode;
}

private boolean isDiagonal(int x, int y) {
    return (x == -1 && y == 1 ||
            x == 1 && y == 1 ||
            x == 1 && y == -1 ||
            x == -1 && y == -1);
}

private float movementCost(float cost, boolean diagonal) {
    return diagonal ? cost + 14 : cost + 10;
}

@Override
public void clearNodes() {
    for (int i = 0; i < map.getTileWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < map.getTileHeight(); j++) {
            if (nodes[i][j].cell != null) {
                nodes[i][j].label.setText("");
                nodes[i][j].f = 0;
                nodes[i][j].h = 0;
                nodes[i][j].g = 0;
                nodes[i][j].arrow.setDrawable("cursor");
                nodes[i][j].arrow.setVisible(false);
                nodes[i][j].parent = null;
            }
        }
    }
    close.clear();
    open.clear();
}
 }
```

Here is the [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) that I'm following. Also my heuristic is a [diagonal distance](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html#breaking-ties)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is in the `isWalkable` method of your `TileMap map` variable.

The image you're following doesn't allow to pass diagonally alongside a wall, where your algorithm does.

You can see this because the score gets added with 14 as follows: 14 + 14 = 28. While you expected it to go as follows: 14 + 10 (going down first) + 10 (going right) = 34.

I hope I explained your problem clearly. I don't know your implementation of `isWalkable`, so I can't provide a full solution but I hope I have pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried to change my heuristic to manhattan distance which doesn't allow to pass diagonally like the guide I'm following but the output is still the same. but I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Did you solve your problem already? Maybe if you update the question to show what you tried I can help you further.

Comment: Nope, not yet. Anyway, from what I don't understand is about the tentative_score(newScore) from the pseudocode. Do you think I'm implementing it right?

Comment: Yes it looks fine to me.